# While loop does not update based on inside parameters

Tags: java

I'm writing code for a game of blackjack, this while loop for some reason never ends even when I enter something other then an H.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean hit = true;
    while (hit = true) {
        System.out.println("Do you want to (H)It or (S)tand");
        String hitorstand = console.next();
        char firstchar = hitorstand.charAt(0);
        if (firstchar == 'H' || firstchar == 'h') {
            hit = true;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This should now be false :)");
            hit = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (hit = true)` should be `while (hit == true)` or simply `while(hit)`. You are setting the boolean to `true` instead of comparing it.

Comment: @maloomeister thank you very much, I wish my IDE was able to pick up that I was comparing a Boolean incorrectly.

Comment: @zPushz checkout IntelliJ Idea with SonarLint plugin. It helps to find suspicious and bad formatted fragments of code and more.

Comment: In Eclipse go to Settings / Java / Compiler / Errors/Warnings / Potential programming problems and enable the warning for Possible accidental boolean assignment

Answer (score 0):

I ran the below code and it works properly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean h;
    
    do {            
        System.out.println("hit(H) or stand(S)");
        String hitOrStand;
        hitOrStand=s.next();
        char hOrS;
        hOrS = hitOrStand.charAt(0);
        if(hOrS=='H' || hOrS=='h')
            h=true;
        else{
            System.out.println("This should now be false :)");
            h = false;
        }
    } while (h);
}
```

Comment: you can also use hitOrStand=s.nextLine();

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your "while(hit = true)" condition. As "hit = true" always returns true & assigns true to hit always.

So modify your while condition as below:

```
while (hit) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to (H)It or (S)tand");
            String hitorstand = console.next();
            char firstchar = hitorstand.charAt(0);
            if (firstchar == 'H' || firstchar == 'h') {
                hit = true;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("This should now be false :)");
                hit = false;
            }
        }
```